# How can we refactor a zustand store code in functional components?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I am using Zustand for global state management.

Here is the code I have to write in order to use store state variables and functions when used in the react functional component.

```
const { token, isLogged, categoryDetail, loginUser, logoutUser, setCategoryDetail } = useUserStore((state) => ({
        token: state.token,
        isLogged: state.isLogged,
        categoryDetail: state.categoryDetail,
        loginUser: state.loginUser,
        logoutUser: state.logoutUser,
        setCategoryDetail: state.setCategoryDetail,
    }));
```

In every functional component, I have to repeat the same code. this leads to repetitive code.

Is there a way to refactor such that I do not have to write the same logic to avail the same variables in multiple functional components?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get your whole state, so really performant, but you could just do:

```
const { token, isLogged, categoryDetail, loginUser, logoutUser, setCategoryDetail } = useUserStore((state) => state);
```

I mean, you can abstract out the useUserStore to another hook, but then you're just abstracting a hook to another hook, right? whats the big benefit?

Remember, you can abstract out the "selector", if you want to pluck out certain things, ala....

```
const userSelector = state => ({
    token: state.token,
    isLogged: state.isLogged,
    categoryDetail: state.categoryDetail,
    loginUser: state.loginUser,
    logoutUser: state.logoutUser,
    setCategoryDetail: state.setCategoryDetail,
});
```

Then use it like so: (you can put the selector in the same file as your userState).

```
const { token, isLogged, categoryDetail, loginUser, logoutUser, setCategoryDetail } = useUserStore(userSelector);
```